# Count all dictionary values by specific key and specific another dictionary value Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have this code:

```
base = [
    {'num': 10, 'bet': '100EUR'},
    {'num': 22, 'bet': '10EUR'},
    {'num': 10, 'bet': '210EUR'},
    {'num': 11, 'bet': '100EUR'},
    {'num': 8, 'bet': '50EUR'},
    {'num': 10, 'bet': '10EUR'},
    {'num': 8, 'bet': '30EUR'},
    {'num': 32, 'bet': '10EUR'}]

newbase = [{'num': b['num'], 'bet': int(b['bet'][:-3])}for b in base]
print(newbase)
```

There are duplicated values for dict 'num' in base. `newbase = [{'num': b['num'], 'bet': int(b['bet'][:-3])}for b in base]` deletes last 3 letter, so to be able to convert it to number. I have to make a program, that counts for each number how is sum of its money, and show 3 numbers with most money in them. For example output have to be like that:

```
10 = 320 EUR
11 = 100 EUR
8 = 80 EUR
```

How to do this?

Comment: Have you tried writing some sort of loop?

Comment: I am new in python - Idk anything

Comment: well, that makes your question a bit broad. "How do I do this" is very literal "by reading an introduction to Python"; someone can surely answer your question, but you're just as stuck with your next problem.

Comment: The whole point of this exercise is for you to figure it out, that's how you learn to program.

Comment: Hint: Create a dictionary whose keys are the `num` values. Loop over `newbase`, check if the `num` is already in the dictionary. If it is, add the current `bet` to its value. If it isn't, create a new key whose value is the current bet.

Comment: I tried searching in web - do not think that I only write questions and copy-paste the answers :) I am just stuck at this thing

Comment: How to loop? Do you mean 'for'?

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm always looking to practice my Python, so here's what I came up with.

```
import itertools

base = [
    {'num': 10, 'bet': '100EUR'},
    {'num': 22, 'bet': '10EUR'},
    {'num': 10, 'bet': '210EUR'},
    {'num': 11, 'bet': '100EUR'},
    {'num': 8, 'bet': '50EUR'},
    {'num': 10, 'bet': '10EUR'},
    {'num': 8, 'bet': '30EUR'},
    {'num': 32, 'bet': '10EUR'}]

# Sort by "num"
base.sort(key=lambda x:x['num'])

# Use groupby to create a list of tuples
# Where index 0 is "num" and index 1 is sum of bet
temp = []
for k,v in itertools.groupby(base, key=lambda x:x['num']):
    temp.append((k, sum(int(x['bet'][:-3]) for x in v)))

# Sort the tuples on bet
temp.sort(key=lambda x:x[1], reverse=True)

for i in range(3):
    print(f"{temp[i][0]} = {temp[i][1]} EUR")
```

Output:

```
10 = 320 EUR
11 = 100 EUR
8 = 80 EUR
```